# ¿Cómo leer en C# un archivo .docx en bytes?

Tags: c#, archivo

¿De qué forma puedo convertir un archivo con extensión *".docx (Word)"* a un array de bytes utilizando *C#*? He probado con el siguiente código, pero solo funciona para archivos de texto.

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path));

string cadena = "";
cadena = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(br.ReadBytes(path.Length));
textBox1.Text = cadena;
br.Dispose();
```

Path simplemente es la ruta del archivo.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [`File.ReadAllBytes(path)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ejemplo:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto te vale para cualquier tipo de fichero:

```
try
{
    byte[] contenido;               
    byte[] buffer = null;
    int longitud;
    var PathfileName = string.Empty;
    PathfileName =   rutaFichero  + @"\" + nombreFichero;               
    using (var fs = new FileStream(PathfileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        longitud = (int)fs.Length;
    }
    contenido = buffer;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{               
   throw ex;
}
```